# How does subprocess.call() work with shell=False?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I am using Python's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module to call some Linux command line functions. The documentation explains the `shell=True` argument as

> If *shell* is `True`, the specified command will be executed through the shell

There are two examples, which seem the same to me from a descriptive viewpoint (i.e. both of them call some command-line command), but one of them uses `shell=True` and the other does not

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
0

>>> subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
1
```

My question is:

- What does running the command with `shell=False` do, in contrast to `shell=True`?
- I was under the impression that `subprocess.call` and `check_call` and `check_output` all must execute the argument through the shell. In other words, how can it possibly *not* execute the argument through the shell?

It would also be helpful to get some examples of:

- Things that can be done with `shell=True` that can't be done with
  `shell=False` and why they can't be done.
- Vice versa (although it seems that there are no such examples)
- Things for which it does not matter whether `shell=True` or `False` and why it doesn't matter

Comment: How do you think the shell starts other (non-shell) programs? There has to be a way for programs to start other programs without a shell, or else the shell couldn't do it either (since a shell is *just another program*).

Comment: Shells aren't fundamental to UNIX. When your system first boots up, it creates a process -- PID 1 -- executing an external binary, traditionally `/sbin/init`. Unless `init` is a shell script, there's no shell involved in running it. `init` can then run other programs likewise without any shell involved; to do that, it duplicates itself (with `fork()`), and then transforms the new copy into a different program (with `execve()`); no shells anywhere in the process. And even when what `init` runs *is* a shell, it uses that same process.

Comment: ...so, honoring the shebang line -- be it `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env` or `#!/usr/bin/python` -- is fundamentally something done *by the kernel* as part of the implementation of `execve()`; a shell is just another program that `execve()` can invoke.

Comment: By contrast, the `system()` call folks are so accustomed to just is a utility function in the C standard library; calling `system("hello")` is a C library call that does a `fork()`; a `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "hello")` in the copy, and a `wait()` in the parent.

Comment: Do you only want answers for Linux? Python subprocess.call() works on Windows too. I ask because this question might be made canonical, so it's good to be general. Also better to know about portability issues.

Comment: @smci I originally ran into this question on Linux, but if there are any non-trivial differences between Windows and Linux, a Windows answer would also be useful! I agree that it's better to be general.

Comment: dkv: I'm trying to say please rewrite your question to not specifically say Linux in the first line, or say "both Windows and Linux answers requested". And untag [tag:linux].

Comment: @smci, it strikes me that the Linux and Windows answers are different enough that a separate Windows question would be better able to attract people with that particular domain expertise. Keeping individual questions' scope narrower avoids the case where you have one answer that covers aspect-X better, and another better covering aspect-Y, and thus don't/can't *have* a single, ideal canonical answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: if we want people to learn to write nice clean portable code, as OS-independent as possible, the last thing we want to do is totally segregate Windows and Linux questions and answers.

Comment: I agree 100% with @smci here... but considering this thread was pretty much settled & constrained to `bash`/`unix` I've decided to open a new one at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873970/how-does-subprocess-popen-works-with-shell-false-on-windows ) for people who's interested about how this works on windows... which I must to say is really tricky... never liked the subprocess.Popen interface too much tbh :/ , that API grew badly since the ancient times.

Comment: @BPL: Best not to do that. That's just fragmenting the knowledge-base. People can contribute a Windows answer on this.

Comment: @smci Yeah, I agree with you... but i wanted to explain the problem I was facing as well as some results after all my hours testing/researching/debugging... and I wasn't sure how to merge it with this specific unix one... Plus, this is not just constrained to bash/unix but also to subprocess.call, which is a particular case of subprocess.Popen...  In fact, thinking backwards it'd been much faster to just bounty this one to find a canonical answer but I didn't really like how the question was formulated. Anyway, I'll see how the other thread evolves (add a reference to this one though)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

UNIX programs start each other with the following three calls, or derivatives/equivalents thereto:

- `fork()` - Create a new copy of yourself.
- `exec()` - Replace yourself with a different program (do this if you're the copy!).
- `wait()` - Wait for another process to finish (optional, if not running in background).

Thus, with `shell=False`, you do just that (as Python-syntax pseudocode below -- exclude the `wait()` if not a blocking invocation such as `subprocess.call()`):

```python
pid = fork()
if pid == 0: # we're the child process, not the parent
  execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NUL);
else:
  retval = wait(pid) # we're the parent; wait for the child to exit & get its exit status
```

whereas with `shell=True`, you do this:

```python
pid = fork()
if pid == 0:
  execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "ls -l", NUL);
else:
  retval = wait(pid)
```

Note that with `shell=False`, the command we executed was `ls`, whereas with `shell=True`, the command we executed was `sh`.

---

That is to say:

```python
subprocess.Popen(foo, shell=True)
```

is exactly the same as:

```python
subprocess.Popen(
  ["sh", "-c"] + ([foo] if isinstance(foo, basestring) else foo),
  shell=False)
```

That is to say, you execute a copy of `/bin/sh`, and direct that copy of `/bin/sh` to parse the string into an argument list and execute `ls -l` itself.

---

So, why *would* you use `shell=True`?

- **You're invoking a shell builtin.**

  For instance, the `exit` command is actually part of the shell itself, rather than an external command. That said, this is a [fairly small set of commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html), and it's rare for them to be useful in the context of a shell instance that only exists for the duration of a single `subprocess.call()` invocation.
- **You have some code with shell constructs (ie. redirections) that would be difficult to emulate without it.**

  If, for instance, your command is `cat one two >three`, the syntax `>three` is a *redirection*: It's not an argument to `cat`, but an instruction to the shell to set `stdout=open('three', 'w')` when running the command `['cat', 'one', 'two']`. If you don't want to deal with redirections and pipelines yourself, you need a shell to do it.

  A slightly trickier case is `cat foo bar | baz`. To do that without a shell, you need to start both sides of the pipeline yourself: `p1 = Popen(['cat', 'foo', 'bar'], stdout=PIPE), p2=Popen(['baz'], stdin=p1.stdout)`.
- **You don't give a damn about security bugs.**

  ...okay, that's a *little* bit too strong, but not by much. Using `shell=True` is dangerous. You can't do this: `Popen('cat -- %s' % (filename,), shell=True)` without a shell injection vulnerability: If your code were ever invoked with a `filename` containing `$(rm -rf ~)`, you'd have a very bad day. On the other hand, `['cat', '--', filename]` is safe with all possible filenames: The filename is purely data, not parsed as source code by a shell or anything else.

  It *is* possible to write safe scripts in shell, but you need to be careful about it. Consider the following:

  ```
    filenames = ['file1', 'file2'] # these can be user-provided
    subprocess.Popen(['cat -- "$@" | baz', '_'] + filenames, shell=True)
  ```

  That code is safe (well -- as safe as letting a user read any file they want *ever* is), because it's passing your filenames out-of-band from your script code -- but it's safe only because the string being passed to the shell is fixed and hardcoded, and the parameterized content is external variables (the `filenames` list). And even then, it's "safe" only to a point -- a bug like [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) that triggers on shell initialization would impact it as much as anything else.

Answer (score 3):

> I was under the impression that subprocess.call and check_call and check_output all must execute the argument through the shell.

No, subprocess is perfectly capable of starting a program directly (via an operating system call).  It does not need a shell

> Things that can be done with shell=True that can't be done with shell=False

You can use `shell=False` for any command that simply runs some executable optionally with some specified arguments.

You must use `shell=True` if your command uses shell features.  This includes pipelines, `|`, or redirections or that contains compound statements combined with `;` or `&&` or `||` etc.

Thus, one can use `shell=False` for a command like `grep string file`.  But, a command like `grep string file | xargs something` will, because of the `|` require `shell=True`.

Because the shell has power features that python programmers do not always find intuitive, it is considered better practice to use `shell=False` unless you really truly need the shell feature.  As an example, pipelines are not really truly needed because they can also be done using subprocess' PIPE feature.

Comment: "must" is a bit strong. Every shell feature -- pipelines included -- can be emulated from Python -- by stringing `Popen` instances together, checking their return values and executing future ones conditionally, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True.  I just added a sentence to emphasize that.

Comment: (I'm likely going to expose the true depth of my ignorance here but...) that's a large part of my confusion - how can subprocess run something like `grep string file` without a shell - isn't `grep` a shell program? (Specifically Linux shell, e.g. it exist for Windows) What does it even mean to run it without a shell?

Comment: @dkv, no, `grep` is not part of the shell. It's an external UNIX executable -- it exists on the filesystem as something like `/usr/bin/grep`, and it can be run with no shell even installed on the system.

Comment: @dkv If you run `type grep`, you'll see that `grep` is an executable file, usually located at `/bin/grep`.  This is in contrast to, for example, `type if` which identifies `if` as a shell command.