# How are command line parameters passed from shell to executable?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, command-line-arguments

When I do something like

```
$ ./my-program foo bar
```

How are `foo` and `bar` passed from the shell to `my-program`'s memory space? Does `my-program` fetch them through a syscall? Is it the kernel's job to copy them?

(Note that I know how to read and use command-line parameters. That's not my question.)

Comment: Yes it's the kernel job. Is this the kind of answer you expect?

Comment: A little more developed answer explaining the mechanics on a high level would be acceptable.

Comment: Eventually (after word-splitting, variable interpolation, etc.) the shell will invoke a member of the `exec*` family of system calls, passing the parameters to it.  `man execve`

Comment: There's the `exec` family of system calls. It creates a process with command line arguments already in place at some predefined address.

Comment: Ahh -- the explanation I had in mind was in a Python-tagged question, [How does `subprocess.call()` work with `shell=False`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990219/how-does-subprocess-call-work-with-shell-false); the mechanism the shell uses to invoke an external command is precisely identical to the mechanism described there, and likewise used by the Python interpreter to itself invoke an external command (or a shell).

Comment: (it's worth noting that the block of memory used by the kernel for storing command-line arguments is also used for environment variables -- hence the more, and larger, environment variables you export, the fewer, and shorter, command-line arguments you can pass).

Comment: ...that said, [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) that a program call `execv`-family call with command-line arguments when it wants to replace itself with a different program, and that the replaced program have its `main()` invoked with those parameters. What happens between the two is an implementation detail; writing software that depends on implementation details is generally bad practice.

Comment: Consider [unix.se] for questions focused on UNIX implementation details as a matter of academic curiosity; StackOverflow's scope is limited to **practical**, answerable questions about software development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is OS specific, but on GNU/Linux:

1. The shell builds the arguments as C strings in its memory space.
2. The shell invokes `execve(2)` and passes a pointer to a NULL terminated array of these arguments.
3. The kernel prepares for execution, including building the new memory map and in particular [allocating the process stack](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/021c91791a5e7e85c567452f1be3e4c2c6cb6063/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L887).
4. The kernel [copies the arguments](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/021c91791a5e7e85c567452f1be3e4c2c6cb6063/fs/exec.c#L1813) into the new stack.
5. The kernel schedules the process from its initial `_start` symbol
6. The target executable is now running
7. The target's glibc initializer (added by gcc) [copies the argument pointer from the stack](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/start.S;h=354d2e6ec78f0eaf9ab0f8ed665c2e5499388df0;hb=b7b88cea4151d85eafd7ababc2e4b7ae1daeedf5#l65).
8. Eventually the target's `main` method is invoked with a pointer to the argument data.
9. The target can now access arguments from its own memory space through the `argv` pointer.