# How does subprocess.Popen works with shell=False on windows?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, subprocess, createprocess

I'd like to understand how [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) works on windows when `shell=False`. In particular, how is the environment or variable expansion taken into consideration by the underlying algorithm?

Consider the below simple test:

```
import os
import subprocess
import textwrap


def truncate(string, width):
    if len(string) > width:
        string = string[:width - 3] + '...'
    return string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = 0
    commands = [
        ["where", "find.exe"],
        "where find.exe",

        [r"c:\windows\system32\where.exe", "find.exe"],
        r"c:\windows\system32\where.exe find.exe",

        ["find.exe", "--version"],
        "find.exe --version",

        r"D:\sources\personal\sublimemerge\Git\usr\bin\find.exe --version",
    ]

    def run(target, shell):
        global index
        label = (
            f'{index:<2}) subprocess.run('
            f'{repr(target)}, shell={shell}, '
            f'stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, '
            f'universal_newlines=True)'
        )
        label = f"{label:<160}"

        try:
            x = subprocess.run(target, shell=shell, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
            print(f"{label} - returncode={x.returncode} - {repr(truncate(x.stdout, 40))}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"{label} - exception={repr(truncate(str(e), 90))}")

        index += 1

    for c in commands:
        run(c, shell=True)
        run(c, shell=False)
```

Where the output looks like this:

```
0 ) subprocess.run(['where', 'find.exe'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                                 - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
1 ) subprocess.run(['where', 'find.exe'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                                - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
2 ) subprocess.run('where find.exe', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                                      - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
3 ) subprocess.run('where find.exe', shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                                     - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
4 ) subprocess.run(['c:\\windows\\system32\\where.exe', 'find.exe'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)      - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
5 ) subprocess.run(['c:\\windows\\system32\\where.exe', 'find.exe'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)     - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
6 ) subprocess.run('c:\\windows\\system32\\where.exe find.exe', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)           - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
7 ) subprocess.run('c:\\windows\\system32\\where.exe find.exe', shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)          - returncode=0 - 'D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\...'
8 ) subprocess.run(['find.exe', '--version'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                             - returncode=0 - 'find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0\nCopyright ...'
9 ) subprocess.run(['find.exe', '--version'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                            - returncode=2 - 'FIND: Parameter format not correct\n'
10) subprocess.run('find.exe --version', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                                  - returncode=0 - 'find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0\nCopyright ...'
11) subprocess.run('find.exe --version', shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)                                 - returncode=2 - 'FIND: Parameter format not correct\n'
12) subprocess.run('D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\usr\\bin\\find.exe --version', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True) - returncode=0 - 'find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0\nCopyright ...'
13) subprocess.run('D:\\sources\\personal\\sublimemerge\\Git\\usr\\bin\\find.exe --version', shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True) - returncode=0 - 'find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0\nCopyright ...'
```

The first question that comes to my mind would be, why do I need to specify the full executable path when `shell=False`? Why is `env` not considered the same way than when `shell=True` is used? Actually... look at cases `5,7`, by just looking at those one would think `env` is being taken into consideration.

I guess the whole matter boils down to understand how `env` is given to [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) call in cpython's [_winapi.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b8f4163da30e16c7cd58fe04f4b17e38d53cd57e/Modules/_winapi.c).

Comment: Commands in `subprocess` should be invoked with their full pathname. This is a very well-known issue. Never rely on your path or order of path components, as your 9),11) do.

Comment: Can you fix your title, also state your actual issue in the first line (not *"Let's start by considering this little test"*). Questions should not be described implicitly in code; then searching, indexing and linking don't work. Your issue seems to be *"How does `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=False` on Windows resolve conflicting path references?"* That's a far less general question than the title implies.

Comment: @smci Mmmm... if this was a well-known issue I wouldn't have wasted a lot of hours trying to figure it out, someone on #python channel would have given me an answer and definitely there wouldn't be any issues such as https://bugs.python.org/issue15451 ... no, it's not a well-known issue and I would expect Popen to use the `env` parent process properly. That includes variable expansion. I agree with your comment about body's content implictely described but not sure about title's... I want to understand how the internals of this works.

Comment: In fact, even further, the provided example is to illustrate one particular problem I've just had because don't fully understanding how shell=False is affecting the algorithm (at the winapi level). I think providing some good references to cpython's code would definitely bring some light here. For instance... would this https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b8f4163da30e16c7cd58fe04f4b17e38d53cd57e/Modules/_winapi.c#L861-L876 be the hot-spot to look at?

Comment: The well-known issue for over a decade is everyone using `subprocess` learned not to trust the shell to generate or disambiguate paths, esp. when conflicting, just pass the full path already. Your case is you want to insist on passing a command without any path, and debug how that environment reference gets resolved by `subprocess` when `shell=False`. (I applaud you working on this, but even if you managed to fix all the bugs, it would still almost surely be platform-, OS- and OS-version-dependent, so not portable code, and shouldn't rely on it. So, less general than the title suggests.)

Comment: @smci Edited my question, please let me know if it can be improved further... I can see you still insist on calling it a "well-known" issue and personally I think that's an unfortunate label... why? Because it implies either i haven't researched enough about this subject or that behaviour is well-docummented... i've used subprocess zillion times since years and yet still I've found myself wasting a lot of time hours today trying to figure out what was going on... In any case, not going offtopic here as I'm really interested on this thread.

Comment: I said the workaround was well-known, and the danger of a package mishandling path conflicts is pretty universal, even if that's only 0.01% likely we wouldn't risk it in production. The cause of the particular buggy behavior, on this particular version of `subprocess` is presumably not. Every non-trivial package has bugs, and if we overlay that risk on multiple OSes and OS versions (both say Windows and MacOS, which intentionally hide or protect some system executables from users, and move paths), we get seriously non-portable code. But it's good that you're helping debug `subprocess`.

Comment: If you looked in the source, you should have seen that `Popen` calls `_winapi.CreateProcess`. The docs for [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) clearly state that if `lpApplicationName` (i.e. the `executable` parameter of `Popen`) isn't used, then it uses the first white-space (and quote) delimited token in `lpCommandLine` (i.e. the `args` parameter of `Popen`, which gets converted to a string by `subprocess.list2cmdline` if it's a sequence).

Comment: If the filename isn't qualified, `CreateProcessW` searches for it in the following directories: the application directory, current directory (but this can and should be disabled), "%SystemRoot%\System32", "%SystemRoot%\System",  "%SystemRoot%", and the directories in `PATH`. If the filename has no extension, it also checks for the name with ".EXE" appended (but not all of the `PATHEXT` extensions, unlike the shell).

Comment: The CMD shell (as used by `shell=True`) searches the current directory by default (this can and should be disabled) and then the `PATH` directories. Note the it doesn't implicitly search the triple of system directories.

Comment: You can use `shutil.which` to search `PATH`, and pass the fully-qualified path as the `executable`. Leave the name in the command line (i.e. `args`) unqualified -- e.g. `["find", "--version"]`.

Comment: How does your *PATH* look like in the console you launch *Python* from?

Comment: @ErykSun Wow, tyvm! I definitely missed that... yeah... at certain point today I was surfing with pdb's and realized `executable` wasn't being used but it didn't bother too much at that time... I should have looked at the `CreateProcessW` docs at that point. So if I've understood correctly... when the filename isn't qualified PATH env var isn't considered and only those paths you've mentioned are used with variable expansion from env? Anyway, really interesting stuff you've brought to the table... that's (as well as msdn refs) really good material to create a nice answer, don't you think :) ?

Comment: @CristiFati The parent's `PATH` process will contain `d:\path\to\gnutils\find.exe;c:\windows\system32; ...` . Just take a look to the cases where i've used the `where` command as it gives a sorted list of `executables` found in PATH.

Comment: @smci Oh, ok, I think I understand now what you meant with the `well-known` labeling, makes sense... I had misunderstood your meaning at first, thx for the clarification.

Comment: @BPL: sure thing. Consider if you launch your script from Windows, DOS shell under Windows, a user-defined Windows shortcut etc. on the exact same system, you might get different behaviors due to different envs (or different run-directories). And might change again under Win11 or MacOS 10.14...

Comment: @smci Yeah.. Speaking of which, as a user, you really need to be aware about how the windows process tree is constructed. For instance, if I'm not mistaken the whole "desktop" window is just an `explorer` process without parent while opening new folders are just explorer child processes spawned from `scvhost.exe`... Things gets weird when you use `setx` and you assume the USER/SYSTEM env vars will affect all the explorer process cos they won't... you need to examine processes properties in case something does't make sense... In fact, I should have researched this problem that way :/

Comment: @BPL, if you're not using `executable` and the command in `args` is not qualified (i.e. contains no explicit directories such as ".\\find"), then the `CreateProcessW` call will search for the executable. It searches the application directory, current directory (if not disabled), and system directories before it searches `PATH`, but it does search `PATH`.

Comment: @ErykSun Makes sense, tyvm. At this point I think I've fully understood how it works... I've just confirmed your last explanation by making a simple test, just renamed `find.exe` that lives in the system directories and you're completely right, it does use `PATH`. Summing up, the right way to fully understand how subprocess.Popen work on win in general is reading `CreateProcess` winapi docs as well as being aware which executable/lpCommandline arguments will be used in both `shell=True` or `shell=False`. Once that happens I'm sure you can say you understand the whole thing :)

Comment: @ErykSun Sorry for going offtopic here but considering your name appears in this [thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue29688), may i ask you whether the fact that Path(r'c:\windows\system32\hostname.exe').resolve() to 'C:/Windows/SysWOW64/HOSTNAME.EXE' is a bug? If I'm not mistaken the underlying call is this one https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4020 . Why am I asking this? Because in early comments i've been suggested to use shutil.which but if i resolve its results i'll get "unmatching" paths.

Comment: @ErykSun I didn't find anything relevant in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew) that helps me to understand whether pathlib.Path.resolve is buggy or not on windows.

Comment: If "System32" resolves to "SysWOW64", it means you're using x86 (32-bit) Python in x64 (64-bit) Windows. x86 programs execute in the WOW64 emulation system. Various filesystem directories and registry keys get automatically redirected to directories and keys intended for x86 programs. For example, "SysWOW64" has 32-bit system binaries. If you need the real native "System32", you can either temporarily disable WOW64 redirection, or use the virtual directory `f'{SystemRoot}\\SysNative'`, where `SystemRoot = os.environ['SystemRoot']`. "SysNative" only exists in an x86 process running under WOW64.

Comment: @ErykSun Mmm, i think i understand... so that basically means  that `pathlib.Path.resolve` is not buggy and is acting like that by design, as a simple wrapper on top of [getfinalpathnamebyhandlew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew), is this correct? Even if such behaviour will produce inconsistencies like `Path(my_path).resolve() != shutil.which(my_path)`. Which leads me to ask... should i resolve when trying to find the exe or not no matter if i use where/which/shutil.which ...?

Comment: `shutil.which('find')` should return a fully-qualified path for "find.exe". This does not have to be resolved as the *final* path.