# How to use `shell find` on Make for windows?

Tags: windows, makefile, find, gnu-make, git-for-windows

I've got a Makefile that contains a statements like this:

- `GO_SOURCES += $(shell find $(GO_DIRS) -type f -name "*.go" -not -path modules/options/bindata.go -not -path modules/public/bindata.go -not -path modules/templates/bindata.go)`

I'm trying to use it on windows and I know using this particular file wouldn't be a problem if I just used cygwin, msys2, vagrant, wsl or any other similar terminal. That said, I'd like to know how to use that Makefile with plain `cmd.exe` terminal (got my own reasons to do so, so please don't suggest using those ;)).

Right now my env var `PATH` has appended the [Git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download) `usr\bin` path
 that contains a nice toolset of ~437 unix commands and find 
 is amongst them.

So for instance, if I run `find` on my terminal... `D:\software\PortableGit\usr\bin\find.exe` will be used instead `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe` as expected, so far so good up to this point.

Problem is when I run the makefile for some reason I haven't understood yet `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe` is trying to be used instead on the statement `$(shell find ...)` so I'll get the error `FIND: Parameter format not correct` when doing `make`.

So basically my question would be, how can I instruct make to use the proper unix find that has higher priority on PATH? But if this wouldn't be possible to achieve easily... would it be possible to make that statement to become more cross-platform maybe using wildcards?

I've already checked the make docs:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell

but I didn't find anything that could help me out.

Also, the version of make I'm using can be downloaded from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm, at the moment of asking this question version I'm using is `GNU Make 3.81`

Comment: Interesting question, I use an environment very similar to yours and ran into the same kind of problem. It doesn't really answer the question, but in my case I decided to use Makefile's `$(wildcard ...)` instead of an OS-specific program. Doesn't work exactly the same, but I managed to make it work in a satisfying way.

Comment: @Tim glad to hear it... I thought I was the only one :) ... Btw, the main reason why I've opened this issue was because I was trying to build gitea and I wanted to avoid switching to msys/cygwin/wsl/ each time i wanted to tweak it... Here you can see the [issue](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/11004) with more detail. I'll definitely try your suggestion with a custom Makefile to see if it works ok but the main problem still remains. Why? Because I'm not sure tweaking an existing Makefile like gitea's to adapt it specifically to our custom setup would be very "nice" :)

Comment: Indeed, might be especially hard if you're not the Makefile maintainer. In my case, I am, so it's easier. Also, Cygwin is forbidden by my IT... Another option might be to override the `PATH` before to call make, just for your running shell. Something like [this](https://superuser.com/a/1240846/975076), and you'd put `D:\software\PortableGit\usr\bin\` in front.On my computer it worked, `where find` correctly finds the `git/usr/bin` version first.

Comment: @Tim Exactly that, when you're not the maintainer you need to adjust to "others rules". Btw, this last suggestion could work and I think is less intrusive than the first one. I mean, in order to avoid modifying the remote Makefile maybe you could have a"master Makefile" that calls the remote Makefile and somehow overrides the PATH as you're explaining... that could do the trick. At first I was thinking about opening an issue to comment them your first suggestion to see if it was possible to convert the makefile a bit more OS-agnostic but now I think i'll try this workaround first, let's see ;)

Comment: @Tim Hold on... I've re read your last suggestion and now I've become confused, at first I thought I'd understood... if you read my post again my PATH env.var is already correct... so what did you mean when said `find` correctly finds the git/usr/bin version first`? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Even if the `PATH` var looks correct, it seems Windows cheats a bit and put System32 first. If you overwrite `PATH` from your shell/Makefile to ensure that your git usr/bin dir comes first, then Windows will correctly use GNU's `find` command rather than the Windows one. It's easy to see if it works. Try `find --help`. With the System32 version you'll have an error. With Git's version you'll see the help text.

Comment: @Tim Ah, ok ok, sure thing. I've understood now your meaning and you're absolutely right... yeah. Wen you spawn a new windows process through the win32 API (handled by the shell) the CreateProcess call will cheat" a bit. There was an interesting discussion related to this topic on a question i'd asked a [while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873970/how-does-subprocess-popen-works-with-shell-false-on-windows) on the comments. In any case, yeah, when the Makefile parsing starts the env.var is wrong so you're forced to overwritte using the grammar accepted by make. Makes sense :)

Comment: *make* uses *CreateProcess* to spawn new processes (e.g. *find*), so *System32* will come 1st no matter what you put in *%PATH%*. A lame workaround (*gainarie*) would be to create a *symlink* to your *find* (maybe for other tools as well) in the current directory. But on another topic "*plain `cmd.exe` terminal (got my own reasons to do so*" smells a bit like an *XY Problem*. Also, *PowerShell* is forbidden as well?

Comment: This question came up in https://superuser.com/questions/1258545/how-to-port-shell-find-name-cpp-on-windows